# How to intersect rows containing an array for a dataframe in pyspark

Tags: dataframe, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, user-defined-functions

I have a dataframe

```
   df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [(2022, 1, 3, '01', ['apple', 'banana', 'orange'],
      [['apple', 'edible', 'fruit', 'green'], ['largest', 'herbaceous', 'flowering', 'plant', 'Vitamin B', 'fruit'],
       ['source', 'Vitamin C', 'fruit']], [['fruit', 2], ['Vitamin', 2]]),
     (2022, 1, 3, '02', ['apple', 'banana', 'avocado'],
     [['apple', 'edible', 'fruit', 'green'], ['largest', 'herbaceous', 'flowering', 'plant', 'Vitamin B', 'fruit'],
      ['medium', 'dark', 'green', 'fruit']], [['fruit', 3], ['green', 2]]),
     (2022, 2, 4, '03', ['pomelo', 'fig'],
     [['citrus', 'fruit', 'sweet'], ['soft', 'sweet']], [['sweet', 2]]), ],
    ['year', 'month', 'day', 'id', "list_of_fruits",
        'collected_tokens', 'most_common_word']
)

+----+-----+---+---+------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------------+
|year|month|day|id |list_of_fruits          |collected_tokens                                                                                                        |most_common_word          |
+----+-----+---+---+------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------------+
|2022|1    |3  |01 |[apple, banana, orange] |[[apple, edible, fruit, green], [largest, herbaceous, flowering, plant, Vitamin B, fruit], [source, Vitamin C, fruit]]  |[[fruit, 2], [Vitamin, 2]]|
|2022|1    |3  |02 |[apple, banana, avocado]|[[apple, edible, fruit, green], [largest, herbaceous, flowering, plant, Vitamin B, fruit], [medium, dark, green, fruit]]|[[fruit, 3], [green, 2]]  |
|2022|2    |4  |03 |[pomelo, fig]           |[[citrus, fruit, sweet], [soft, sweet]]                                                                                 |[[sweet, 2]]              |
+----+-----+---+---+------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------------
```

I want to groupby by year, day, and month and intersect rows containing a list, a list of lists and a list with a key and min value (the last three columns respectively). In the end, I would like this result

```
+----+-----+---+---+---------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------+
|year|month|day|id |intersection_list_of_fruits|intersection_collected_tokens                                                             |intersection_most_common_word|
+----+-----+---+---+---------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------+
|2022|1    |3  |01 |[apple, banana]            |[[apple, edible, fruit, green], [largest, herbaceous, flowering, plant, Vitamin B, fruit]]|[[fruit, 2]]                 |
|2022|1    |3  |02 |[apple, banana]            |[[apple, edible, fruit, green], [largest, herbaceous, flowering, plant, Vitamin B, fruit]]|[[fruit, 2]]                 |
|2022|2    |4  |03 |[pomelo, fig]              |[[citrus, fruit, sweet], [soft, sweet]]                                                   |[[sweet, 2]]                 |
+----+-----+---+---+---------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------+
```

So in the column `intersection_list_of_fruits` missing `[orange],[avocado]`, in the column `intersection_collected_tokens` missing `[source, Vitamin C, fruit], [medium, dark, green, fruit]` and in the column `intersection_most_common_word` missing `[Vitamin, 2], [green, 2]`.

I know about `array_intersect`, but I need to look at the **intersection by row**, and also need to use an aggregation function due to groupby - to group ids with the same date and intersect them. (I think this can be done using spark's applyInPandas function)

Comment: Do you also deal with scenarios where in for the same year, month, day there are more than 2 rows? Which version of Spark are you using?

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/66207692/2956135

Comment: Yes, there are more than two rows, but I showed an example with two. I have a huge dataframe and I do not know exactly how many identical rows there will be. I am using spark version 3.1.2

Comment: Thanks Emma, this is useful, but I have a list in the list and also values with keys and I don't quite understand what to do with them and how to intersect them

Comment: At least `list_of_fruits` and `collected_tokens` worked for me with the code in the link.  `most_common_word` is not clear yet. You have value of `fruit, 2` and `fruit, 3`, which one do you want to keep?

Comment: I want to keep  the smallest value for the key. It will be 2.

Comment: hmm, Off the top of my head, I don't know the easy way to intersect only by the element within the array.   I could find the smallest number groupby the same word in `most_common_word` and update all array to the smallest number, then apply the `expr` method in the link.  But that feels unsettling

Comment: I understand, then I think it will be good if it will just be either fruit,3 or fruit,2 in the column

Comment: The hard part is more about trying to find intersection with the partially matching rather than picking up anything.  
So either matching the number value such that you can have full match similar to other columns or you might have better luck with exploding the column and aggregate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `aggregate` and `array_intersect`, along with `collect_set` to compute the intersection on `list_of_fruits` and  `collected_tokens` to obtain `intersection_list_of_fruits` and `intersection_collected_tokens`.

However, since `intersection_most_common_word` needs to account for the count of the words. To do this,

1. Find the intersections of words excluding counts
2. Iterate over the intersection words and the collect arrays in `most_common_word` and find the minimum count

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql import Window as W
from pyspark.sql import Column

df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [(2022, 1, 3, '01', ['apple', 'banana', 'orange'],
      [['apple', 'edible', 'fruit', 'green'], ['largest', 'herbaceous', 'flowering', 'plant', 'Vitamin B', 'fruit'],
       ['source', 'Vitamin C', 'fruit']], [['fruit', 2], ['Vitamin', 2]]),
     (2022, 1, 3, '02', ['apple', 'banana', 'avocado'],
     [['apple', 'edible', 'fruit', 'green'], ['largest', 'herbaceous', 'flowering', 'plant', 'Vitamin B', 'fruit'],
      ['medium', 'dark', 'green', 'fruit']], [['fruit', 3], ['green', 2]]),
     (2022, 2, 4, '03', ['pomelo', 'fig'],
     [['citrus', 'fruit', 'sweet'], ['soft', 'sweet']], [['sweet', 2]]), ],
    ['year', 'month', 'day', 'id', "list_of_fruits",
        'collected_tokens', 'most_common_word']
)

def intersection_expr(col_name: str, window_spec: W) -> Column:
    lists = F.collect_set(col_name).over(window_spec)
    return F.aggregate(lists, lists[0], lambda acc,x: F.array_intersect(acc, x))



def intersect_min(col_name: str, window_spec: W) -> Column:
    # Convert array into map of word and count and collect into set
    k = F.transform(F.col(col_name), lambda x: x[0])
    v = F.transform(F.col(col_name), lambda x: x[1])
    map_count = F.map_from_arrays(k, v)
    map_counts = F.collect_list(map_count).over(window_spec)
    
    # Find keys present in all list
    keys = F.transform(map_counts, lambda x: F.map_keys(x))
    intersected = F.aggregate(keys, keys[0], lambda acc,x: F.array_intersect(acc, x))
    
    # For intersection find the minimum value
    res = F.transform(intersected, lambda key: F.array(key, F.array_min(F.transform(map_counts, lambda m: m.getField(key)))))
    
    return res

window_spec = W.partitionBy("year", "month", "day").orderBy("id").rowsBetween(W.unboundedPreceding, W.unboundedFollowing)

(df.select("year", "month", "day", "id",
        intersection_expr("list_of_fruits", window_spec).alias("intersection_list_of_fruits"), 
        intersection_expr("collected_tokens", window_spec).alias("intersection_collected_tokens"),
        intersect_min("most_common_word", window_spec).alias("intersection_most_common_word"))
    .show(truncate=False))


"""
+----+-----+---+---+---------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------+
|year|month|day|id |intersection_list_of_fruits|intersection_collected_tokens                                                             |intersection_most_common_word|
+----+-----+---+---+---------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------+
|2022|1    |3  |01 |[apple, banana]            |[[apple, edible, fruit, green], [largest, herbaceous, flowering, plant, Vitamin B, fruit]]|[[fruit, 2]]                 |
|2022|1    |3  |02 |[apple, banana]            |[[apple, edible, fruit, green], [largest, herbaceous, flowering, plant, Vitamin B, fruit]]|[[fruit, 2]]                 |
|2022|2    |4  |03 |[pomelo, fig]              |[[citrus, fruit, sweet], [soft, sweet]]                                                   |[[sweet, 2]]                 |
+----+-----+---+---+---------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------+
"""
```

Comment: Wow, I couldn't think of how to make the minimum values, thank you very much!